# Get one single random image from a specific user liked images with Unsplash API

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest

I am currently using the source.unsplash.com service where I can get a random image from the collection of my liked images with this URL.

```
https://source.unsplash.com/user/pizaranha/likes
```

Everything works perfectly, but I can't get the image information as the author to give credits.

Then I started using Unsplash Api, where I can get the author information and all the images I like in a json array with this url.

```
"https://api.unsplash.com/users/pizaranha/likes/?client_id="+clientId;
```

My question is how could I get just a random item and not the entire list of images that I like.

A workaround that works is to use a random index to pick an object from the array, BUT I think it is not efficient in terms of bandwidth because I get a large array with a bunch of elements instead of a single element.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If Unsplash API don't give you a away to do this. It mean that you have to get whole list and pick random image yourself using JavaScript. if don't know how you can split the problem into parts. "How to fetch JSON from the server", "How to pick random object from an array", and "how to create an image dynamically in JavaScript"

Comment: Thank you @jcubic . I've already done it that way until the API has the option I'm asking for.

Comment: Maybe you should ask Unsplash support if they have what you need. Asking question about specific API on StackOverflow where you already know more than most people here is kind of pointless.

Comment: @jcubic thank you for your help. It makes some sense because if someone in the future faces the same problem, this question might help. Also, if Unsplash sees this question on SO, they might as well give a proper approach to solve it. By the way, the first thing I did was ask the Unsplash support team (no answer yet ). But I believe in the magic of SO and this could help more people.